# Authentication Strategy for GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication

I have an application deployed to Google App Engine. Within the application, there are 2 roles: standard user, and administrator. I have form based authentication setup, and the URL's that require authentication (for example /admin and /account) are setup to require any role (*), just so I can be sure that Google has authenticated them. I have a filter setup for the admin path as well as the account path that talks to backend business logic to see if the user has an account within my application before forwarding them to the page they requested, or redirecting if necessary.

This seems cumbersome, in that for each request, the filter uses the UserService to get the google user in order to determine whether or not the person authenticated by google has an account within the application. I know that within the context of an application deployed to a traditional application server, I could actually define the application level role required to access a url, and since the application server would know about the roles/users for the application, that would be sufficient, but since google is handling the authentication, would I be correct in assuming that I have to handle the access requirements on a per request basis, as I am now with the use of filters? I chose to use filters to try to keep the actual servlet 'cleaner', so that I know that when a client request reaches the servlet, they have been authenticated and are authorized to access those resources.

Would it be wise to carry that data around (whether a user is authenticated and whether or not they are an admin or standard user) in a session? That's the only other alternative I can come up with. I'm not sure how expensive it is to access the UserService for every single request, because that is in turn accessing the datastore. I would imagine there has to be a better way to handle authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if it's an optimal solution but what we do now is store a User session (our own implementation, not GAEs) and we cache it aggressively using Objecitfy's cache feature. That way we only hit the datastore on login/logout and most queries after that are virtually free (because of the use standard  session time on our app, cache flush is not really a concern)

Comment: I'm thinking along the lines of a cache as well. One that holds the id's for all the user accounts, and one that holds the id's for all the administrators, and those caches would be updated as new accounts are created. That way, the filters can talk to the cache as opposed to the datastore.

Comment: Bear in mind memcache is volatile. You'll have to reload them several times after you created them.